# Stop a updatetimer in android

Tags: android, timer, elapsedtime

I try to create a custome elapse time and it will start the timer once i hold the volume key and suppose the time must stop after i release the key but i have problem when i release the key the timer still moving. Please advise on what I'm missing thanks

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN  && shouldCont == true && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)){
            startRecord();
            repeat = true;
            if(repeat == true  && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN ){
            t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

```
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        long timeGoneMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

                        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer); 
                        tv.setText(""+util.milliSecondsToTimer(timeGoneMillis));                         
                    }

                });
            }

        },
        //Set how long before to start calling the TimerTask (in milliseconds)
        0,
        //Set the amount of time between each execution (in milliseconds)
        1000);}
        shouldCont = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that we cant actually Kill the timer instances by using cancel() so I just added t.cancel() and the timer instances will stop.